# Why is there a need to link with `printf.o` if it's already defined inside `stdio.h`?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

As far as I understand when we include `stdio.h` the entire file is copied into the text of our program.(basically we prepend it) Then when we do a function call for `printf()` why does it have to be linked first?

Is it that `stdio.h` contains just the definitions of those functions and the compiler finds the compiled executable object file for the function that we invoke for example `printf()`.

I've read about this in a few places but still kinda not clear.

Comment: Time to learn the difference between a *declaration* and a *definition*, and about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). For functions, a *declaration* is telling the compiler that the function exists somewhere in the program, in some translation unit. A *definition* for a function is the actual implementation of the function, its code.

Comment: When you do `#include <stdio.h>`, all you effectively get is the line `extern int printf(const char *fmt, ...);`, and similarly for the other standard I/O functions.  So that tells your program (or tells the compiler, as it's compiling your program) how to *call* the function "`printf"`, but it doesn't give it any actual, callable, runnable *code* for the function `printf`.  Getting the actual code is what you need to link against the correct library for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Header files like stdio.h generally just contain a declaration that defines the name of the function, the types of its arguments, and its return value.  This is enough for the compiler to generate calls to the function, but it is not a definition.  The actual code that implements the function is going to be in a library (with an extension like `.a` or `.o` or `.lib`).

Comment: Are the corresponding `.o` files generated during compile phase or they just sitting there waiting for the linker to use?

Comment: @CupOfGreenTea: They're normally shipped as part of the standard library, which may be linked either statically (from a file with suffix `.lib` or `.a`, which are a lot like ZIP files, containing the `.o`-s), or dynamically (`.so`, or `.dll`), where the use of a lib file serves just as a placeholder. In either case, `printf.o` in one form or another is shipped together with the build tools and/or the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  `printf()` is included in `libc.so` (this is where the `printf()` function resides), which is the C standard library.  The compiler includes automatically `-lc` as option, when it calls the linker, so you don't need to add that option.  Only in case you link your object files calling the linker `ld` directly, is when you need to include the option yourself (and some other files that form the C runtime, the linker doesn't know that you are linking a C source program, so it doesn't know what files to link with your modules, but the compiler does)  See the documentation of the compiler you use, or just use the `-v` option when building the executable, to see the command line the compiler uses to call the linker, and you will see all the objects and libraries the compiler requires for every C program.